# How i can make method works in Timer?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I created draw() method that paints the value of variable z on screen. Timer should increase z and call draw() every time but draw() only works outside timer. I have zero errors in console. Any ideas? 
Here's my code:

```
public class New extends JFrame{

    MyComponent komponent;
    int z=1;
    Timer timer;

    class MyComponent extends JComponent{

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g2){
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)g2;
            RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
                     RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setRenderingHints(rh);

            timer=new Timer(50,new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    draw(g); //doesn't work
                    z++;
                }
            });
            timer.start();
            draw(g); //works

        }
        private void draw(Graphics2D g){
            Font myFont = new Font ("Courier New", 1, 30);
            g.setFont(myFont);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString(Integer.toString(z),0,30);
        }
    }
```

and whole code:
https://pastebin.com/mH2u9YVr

Comment: How do you run that code? Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Please provide a code where you call `paintComponent()`

Comment: Simply put, Swing isn't thread safe and starting a new thread (which is what Timer does) and calling draw from that won't work. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to draw something on canvas and in next timer tick i want draw something on that previous canvas and so on. Something like layers in photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the timer and starting it inside `paintComponent()` is the problem. `paintComponent()` is a method which get invoked very frequently. So, your `timer` is created many times again and again.

You need to create the timer and start it only once.

I got your full code and made few changes. I think now it works. See my comments in the code as well.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class New extends JFrame{

  MyComponent komponent;
  int z=1;
  Timer timer;

  class MyComponent extends JComponent{

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g2){
      Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)g2;
      RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
          RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
          RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g.setRenderingHints(rh);

      //Prasad: Removed the timer from here

      draw(g);

    }
    private void draw(Graphics2D g){
      Font myFont = new Font ("Courier New", 1, 30);
      g.setFont(myFont);
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawString(Integer.toString(z),0,30);
    }
  }

  public New(String string) {
    super(string);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Toolkit kit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension d=kit.getScreenSize();
    setBounds(d.width/4, d.height/4, d.width/2, d.height/2);
    add(komponent=new MyComponent());

    //Prasad: Moved the timer here
    timer=new Timer(500,new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        komponent.repaint(); //Prasad: Just call repaint()
        z++;
      }
    });
    timer.start();

    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new New("New");
      }

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That was my previous version of code but this time i need draw something on previous canvas. I mention it in comment under my question. I just want to paint on first canvas all the time. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @kapsztat12, if you want multiple layers, you have to add multiple `MyComponent` components to the frame.

Comment: @kapsztat12, I got your code from that "whole code" link you have given in the question. If your code is different now, please update it there. (or atleast remove the link from the question)